# Unending hCaptchas from CloudFlare sites?

Tags: captcha, cloudflare

Lately I've been unable to get past the CloudFlare hCaptcha challenges for certain sites. It just keeps serving the same "One more step" page after I complete each hCaptcha.  This didn't use to be the case, I used to be able to access these sites after only one challenge.

I don't think I'm making mistakes when I identify the umbrellas, airplanes, bicycles, etc.  But It seems no matter how many times I do this, I can never make it past the page.
Choosing "New Tor connection for this site" doesn't help either.

What's going on, and how do I get past this?

(Using Tor mode in Brave browser.)

Comment: This is a common problem when using Tor. There's no good solution, this is just CloudFlare blocking Tor users. You may have better luck using the Tor Browser instead since CloudFlare sometimes adds exceptions to allow Tor Browser users.

Comment: Hi sh37211, I almost predominantly use the Tor Browser, apparmored or selinuxed depending on machine, and often come across them. I know nothing of the validity of this approach, and am not an expert in security at all, but I often can get past these problems by entering the website in something like kproxy.com, from within Tor Browser. Sometimes Cloudflare will say there is a host error and if I try it with kproxy it works...

Comment: Thanks guys.  I have found much better luck now using Tor Browser (@Steve's suggestion) than using Tor within Brave, although it will require some fine tuning of the allowed scripts, because in Tor Browser the sites don't layout properly whereas with Brave's Tor they "just worked".

Comment: Glad to hear it helped :) Hopefully some day in the future fewer sites block Tor users.